# Docker Swarm scale up containers with volumes

Tags: docker, containers, swarm, volumes

I have a php-fpm container and a volume with application code which is attached to php-fpm container. Some application logs should be written inside application volume.

What I want to know what is the right way when you want to scale horizontally php-fpm container. If new container will be mounted to same volumes, what will happed with parallel writes to files? Or each new container will create a new volume?

Comment: Do you really need a log file? I mean your app could use stdout/stderr and send it to a centralized logging system.

Comment: well is an php application(magento 2) that has it own var/logs/ folder where is putting its own logs. I want to be minimum invasive in app code since it will be generated using composer and composer.json is retrieved from git.

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?

Comment: in the docker documentation it says that containers should be kept as small as possible and you are encouraged to use volumes. In my case, when application that this custom behavior, I want to know how can I scale horizontally containers with volumes in order to avoid concurrent writes to same file.